# sql plus create method body

Tags: oracle, methods, sqlplus

I have done the following and having problem in creating body type. please help!!

```
 SQL> desc theater_t
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 TNO                                                NUMBER
 NAME                                               VARCHAR2(15)
 ADDRESS                                            ADDRESS_TY
 PHONE                                              PH_TY
 START_DATE                                         DATE
 END_DATE                                           DATE

METHOD
------
 MEMBER FUNCTION FEATURED_DAYS RETURNS NUMBER

SQL> desc theaters
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 TNO                                                NUMBER
 NAME                                               VARCHAR2(15)
 ADDRESS                                            ADDRESS_TY
 PHONE                                              PH_TY
 START_DATE                                         DATE
 END_DATE                                           DATE

SQL> desc nowshowing
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 FILM                                      NOT NULL NUMBER
 THEATER                                            REF OF THEATER_T
```

Theaters is a table of type theater_t. I want to create a featured_days that returns end_date-start_date. But I am not able to do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE type theater_t AS OBJECT
     (    tno        NUMBER,
          name       VARCHAR2(10),
          address    VARCHAR2(20),
          phone      NUMBER,
          start_date DATE,
          end_date   DATE,
          member FUNCTION featured_days
          return number);
```

The body part I've creted is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY theater_t
IS
     MEMBER FUNCTION FEATURED_DAYS  RETURN NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
     RETURN (end_date- start_date);
END;
END;
/
```

You could return the value of the FEATURED_DAYS as:

```
SET serveroutput ON
declare
     obj theater_t := theater_t ( 1,'ajmal','my_address',9876,to_date('01-jan-2013','dd-mon-yyyy'),to_date('07-feb-2013','dd-mon-yyyy'));
BEGIN
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (obj.name||' '||obj.featured_days||' days');
END;
```

And you'll get:

```
anonymous block completed

ajmal 37 days
```

hope this is what you're trying.